# How define shortcuts to specific OptionInspector points?

Tags: keyboard

I often assign label to cells by OptionInspector (SHIFT + CRTL + O) > CellFrame > etc. It would be great to have the possibility to jump directly to CellFrameLabel or, even better, to edit the label simply clicking on it. Any hint ? P.S. If it matters, in this period I'm using ver. 8.0.1.0

Comment: This will make a button that sets the label to values specified by `t`. maybe you can use `KeyEventTranslations.tr` to make a shortcut for it. `t = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
Button["cell frame", 
 SetOptions[SelectedCells[InputNotebook[]][[1]], 
  CellFrameLabels -> {{t[[1]], t[[2]]}, {t[[3]], t[[4]]}}]]`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't understend what `SelectedCells` means.
So I have tried this variant: `t = {"a", "a", "a", "a"}; Button["cell frame",SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]],CellFrameLabels -> {{t[[1]], t[[2]]}, {t[[3]], t[[4]]}}]]` and it seems to work.. Please can you enlighten me ?

Comment: I think `SelectedCells` refers to the cell with the input cursor, or selected via the bracket at the right side of the cell.

Comment: An useful trick, to set labels to progressive numbers: `counter = 0;
Button["cell frame", SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
  CellFrameLabels -> {{ToString[++counter], None}, {None, None}}]]` .
Unfortunately, it work only as long as counter is defined. After the notebook has been closed and reopend how can I get the last label assigned and put it tn  `counter` ?.

Comment: `Dynamic[counter, SaveDefinitions -> True]` may save the counter; but bear in mind `SaveDefinitions` is considered a bit dangerous [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579644/savedefinitions-considered-dangerous).

Comment: To get the full list of all labels should be possible use something resembling this code (it works fine, whithin its scope):
`Button["btn", 
 Print@TableForm[Options[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]]]]]`
but with `NotebookSelection` replaced by the complete list of cells.
Any method simpler than parsing
`cl = First @ NotebookGet @ EvaluationNotebook[];
cl = Flatten @ (Options /@ cl)` ?